# How do I return multiple integers when the return type is simply int?

Tags: java

I have to implement the following function:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // smth
}
```

However, this function may have zero or more solutions, I mean no solution (then should return -1), one solution, two solutions, etc. As you see the function just has `int` as return type (not an array) and I cannot change it. What should I do, if for example this function should return two values (5 and 9) or three values (1, 10, and 7)? How can I return them?

I thought about tuples, but I believe there is a better way to solve it.

Comment: If you can't change the return type, there is not much you can do (unless you use the input array to store the output).

Comment: Thanks Eran, I was afrais about that.

Comment: you should discuss the question with the person who defined the signature of that method

Comment: codility :/ it's not possible to discuss with this machine

Comment: Another option is that one of the indices of the input array will specify which of the n solutions to return in each call to the method. Each call would return one solution, but different calls will return different solutions.

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/masking.html.

Comment: @RafalIwaniak then probably it is a trick question testing your creativity. Encode multiple values in a single int, throw an Exception containing the information etc. Not really the focus of this site.

Comment: An `int` is encoded on 32 bits in Java. If the possible results have some good constraints, it is possible to put a lot of information in 32 bits...

Comment: If the return type of int cannot be changed, but the inputs can be changed, then you could pass in another variable by ref and hence return the solutions. Or you could use another function within that function to store the solutions elsewhere in the program. If you have access to the source, then I see no reason why you can't change the method signature to accommodate your requirements, past AND present. Or overload that method signature

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use crypting? This only works, if your solutions and numbers of solutions are small and you know two upper limits (number of solutions and biggest size of solution), but you can put more information in one int. Here `mult` is a number greater than the greatest expected solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    //solution is an array of your solutions
    for(i=0; i<solution.length; i++){
        returnValue=returnValue*mult;
        returnValue+=solution[i];
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public List<Integer> retrieveSolutions(int solution){
    List<Integer> decryptedSolutions = new ArrayList<>();
    while(solution>mult){
        decryptedSolutions.add(solution%mult);
        solution = (int) solution/mult;
    }
    return decryptedSolutions;
}
```

Just beware the case solution=0 is ignored here and you might get bigger values than the max-Value of Integer (hence you have to make sure, your upperBound+1 (=mult) power the biggest number of solutions+1 is smaller than the max-Value of Integer). Also negative solutions would break this (you can avoid this, if you know the lower bound of the solutions). An alternative would be (as mentioned in the comments) to put the solutions in an mutable Object given in the arguments:

Either in the array as Peter stated in his answer (works only, if the argument array has more elements, than your solutions) and now you have the solutions in the given array and the return value tells how many solutions you got:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int numberSolutions = solutions.length;
    for(int i=0; i<solutions.length; i++){
        A[i]=solutions[i];
    }
    return numberSolutions;
}
```

or in an extra "bag"

```
public int solution(int[] A, NumberBag putTheSolutionsHere) {
   // puts solutions in your NumberBag, whatever Object you might want to use here (preferable List implementation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the signature, you only option is to change the input.  While that would be the worst possible solution, it might be your only one.  You could return the number of solutions. e.g.

```
// return all the positive numbers
public int solution(int[] array) {
   // put all the positive numbers at the start.
   return numOfPositives;
}
```

A better solution would be to return an array of results

```
public int[] solution(int[] input)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function, overload it - write the same function with different signature.

[more on overloading](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add one argument to the signature, add any `Collection` and the method will populate the `Collection` (trivial).

If you cannot change the signature and cannot change the return type : is it for a good reason? Discuss with the one who asked you to do it.

If there is a good reason for that (or if it is a sort of algorithmic exercise), you can use some **bit masking**. In java, an int is encoded on 32 bits. If the possible solution are smalls, you can divide those 32 bits in small groups and store each solution in a group.

Here is a solution which shows how you could store up to 8 solutions in `[0; 15]` by using groups of 4 bits:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(5, 7, 3, 8, 9);
  String collect = values.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
  System.out.println("Values to encode : "+collect);

  int _1111 = (2 << 3) - 1;
  System.out.println("\nMasks : ");
  for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(padWith0(Integer.toString(_1111 << 4 * i, 2)));
  }

  System.out.println("\nEncoding : ");
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< values.size() ; i++) {
    int partial = values.get(i) << (4 * i);
    System.out.println(values.get(i) +" => " + padWith0(Integer.toString(partial, 2)));
    result += partial;
  }
  System.out.println("  => "+Integer.toString(result, 2));

  System.out.println("\nRestitution : ");

  for(int i = 0; i< values.size(); i++) {
    int mask = _1111 << (4 * i);
    int partial = (result & mask) >> (4 * i);
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(partial, 2) +" => " + partial);
  }
}

public static String padWith0(String s) {
  return ("00000000000000000000000000000000" + s).substring(s.length());
}
```

Output :

```
Values to encode : 5, 7, 3, 8, 9

Masks : 
00000000000000000000000000001111
00000000000000000000000011110000
00000000000000000000111100000000
00000000000000001111000000000000
00000000000011110000000000000000

Encoding : 
5 => 00000000000000000000000000000101
7 => 00000000000000000000000001110000
3 => 00000000000000000000001100000000
8 => 00000000000000001000000000000000
9 => 00000000000010010000000000000000
  => 00000000000010011000001101110101

Restitution : 
101 => 5
111 => 7
11 => 3
1000 => 8
1001 => 9
```